# Close other dropdown on click in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

This is the simple dropdown component I use.

```
<script>
    let show = false;
</script>

<div>
    <button on:click={() => show = !show }>Show Dropdown</button>
    {#if show}
        <div>
            <a href="/">Option 1</a>
            <a href="/">Option 2</a>
            <a href="/">Option 3</a>
            <a href="/">Option 4</a>
        </div>
    {/if}
</div>

<style>
    a { display: block; }
</style>
```

I am using this component in parent three times as follow:

```
<script>
    import Dropdown from './dropdown.svelte';
</script>

<div>
    <Dropdown />
    <Dropdown />
    <Dropdown />
</div>
```

Once I click first dropdown its respective dropdown content opens, but upon clicking next dropdown how do I close previous dropdowns and open only the one that is clicked?

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this a common method is to add a `click` event handler at the top and trigger closing that way. You just have to exclude the case where the click happens inside the dropdown.

```html
<script>
    let show = false;
    let container;
    
    function onWindowClick(e) {
        if (container.contains(e.target) == false)
            show = false;
    }
</script>

<svelte:window on:click={onWindowClick} />

<div bind:this={container}>
    <button on:click={() => show = !show }>Show Dropdown</button>
    ...
</div>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c7ccdcb825e641a18d9e167799dc1624?version=3.48.0)

(Event handlers added via [`svelte:window`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-window) are cleaned up automatically.)

It is important to use the correct elements for accessibility reasons. Links should be `a` Element, otherwise clickable things should be `button` elements. This allows proper keyboard interaction and provides semantics to screen readers.

Ideally, elements also should be supplied with the correct ARIA attributes (like `role`) where appropriate and keyboard interactions like up/down arrow navigation, close on Escape and the like should be implemented. ([See guidelines](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/menu-button/menu-button-links).)

Comment: Agree, it's better to keep tags intact for both screen readers and ease of use, thank you

Comment: You can use `<svelte:window>` instead of relying on `onMount` and `document.addEventListener`

Comment: @StephaneVanraes: True, simplifies the code a bit, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well i never touched svelte but i know an method how to do it.

You can use `focus` and `blur` events

You add `tabindex="0"` to the element and whenever you open it, you focus the element. Now, whenever you click outside of the element the blur event will be triggered. It even gets triggerd if you click outside of your browser.

```
<script>
import { tick } from 'svelte';
let show = false;
let dropdownElement;
async function showDropdown() {
    show = !show;
    //we need to wait with tick, until DOM nodes have mounted
    await tick();
    dropdownElement.focus()
}
</script>

<div>
    <button  on:click={ showDropdown }>Show Dropdown</button>
    {#if show}
        <div  on:blur={() => show = false} tabindex="0" bind:this={dropdownElement}>
            <div>Option1</div>
            <div>Option2</div>
            <div>Option3</div>
        </div>
    {/if}
</div>
```

I use `div` instead of `a` tags because when you click on the `a` tags, the parent loses its focus.

Comment: Using the correct element for a particular task is important for accessibility. This is a hack that prevent using interacting with the options via the keyboard and things like screen readers lack critical information about what the elements represent.