# Display a menu only on the targeted button Sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am new to sveltekit and I am developing an app as a CMS.

On the admin area, I display all the posts already published with a button for each post. When I press the button I want to have a dropdown menu that only goes down to the clicked post.

Currently, I use a boolean to show or hide the dropdown menu, except that this way the menu appears and disappears on all posts, not just the clicked one. Example on the image:

[image: Problem image]

Do you have a solution or do you know where I can go to find the answer?

Thanks in advance, have a nice day.

Comment: This is similar to [tracking focus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73450006/546730). The answer should apply as well. One additional wrinkle is that a click outside should close the menu...

Comment: See also [Close other dropdown on click in svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72896690/546730)

Comment: With a Svelte use:action you can control a menu instance for a blog post (node).  Use:action example explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0GqIoo66i0g